# I have issue with coingate api

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a bitcoin API to receive payments on my site and I am using laravel and php 7.2. This is part of my coingate api code

```
 $post_params = array(
            'order_id'          =>  $transaction->id,
            'token'             =>  $transaction->hash,
            'price'             =>  $transaction->price,
            'currency'          =>  $currency,
            'receive_currency'  =>  $receive_currency,
            'callback_url'      => route('ipn.coingate',['token' => $transaction->hash]),
            'cancel_url'        => route('billing.fail'),
            'success_url'       => route('billing.success'),
        );
```

and this is call back url script (ipn controller)

```
 $order = Transaction::find($request->input('order_id'));
        if ($request->input('token') == $order->hash) {
            $savedata = null;
            if ($request->input('status') == 'paid') {
                if ($request->input('price') >= $order->price) {
                    $savedata['confirmation'] = $request->input('id');
                    $savedata['gateway_response'] = json_encode($request->all());
                    $savedata['status'] = 'paid';

                    //Update product sales
                    $this->salesupdate($da->product_id);
                    //Save order
                    $this->neworder($order->user_id,$da->product_id,$order->price,$order->hash,$order->id);
                    //Save user transaction
                    $this->newusertransaction($da->user_id,$da->price);
                    //Credit seller
                    $this->creditseller($da->product_id);
                }
```

The issue here is that when payment on coingate is done, it returns to the success_url without doing the functions in the callback url(ipn Controller)

I want when the payment is done to return to callback url(ipn Controller)
 to  do what in the file

Comment: I have a similar issue with the ruby library. I do understand that the user is never redirected to the callback url, they are redirected to success_url. However, the callback is never called anyways. I know it's been a while but did you solve this? The developer support is null, they won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

success_url is where the customer gets redirected when they finish the payment. Callback_url is where CoinGate will send the callbacks too, the callback function has to be triggered by a callback from Coingate and not from finishing a payment.